# Split up a four-digit number in verilog

Tags: verilog

For my application I can have a number from 0 to 9999 which I need to put on 4 seven segment displays.

The main issue I have got is splitting the number up into the 4 digits, I have thought of several methods:

1. have multiple if statements for each number (very long winded and not the best choice)
2. use if statements to determine the number of 10's, 100's etc (less long winded but stil alot of code)

Is there a better way of doing this? (i am very sure that there is)

Comment: you have to implement bin2bcd convertion http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you could just divide the number by 10, 100, and 1000 (taking the result and the remainder) and that would tell you how many ones, tens, hundreds, and thousands are in your number.

However since division/modulo is an expensive operation in verilog, you might want to try an approach that is more efficient in area/logic, but less efficient in time.

One idea is to just count, one cycle at a time, how many of each column is in your number with some separate counters:

some untested pseudocode:

```
input [13:0] mynumber;
input        start;
output       done;

reg   [13:0] counter;
reg   [3:0]  ones;
reg   [3:0]  tens;
reg   [3:0]  hundreds;
reg   [3:0]  thousands;
reg          done;

always @ posedge clk begin
    if(start) 
        counter <= 0;
    else if(counter == mynumber)
        done <= 1;
    else begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        ones <= ones == 9 ? 0 : ones + 1;
        if(ones == 9) begin
            tens <= tens == 9 ? 0 : tens + 1;
            if(tens == 9) begin
                hundreds <= hundreds == 9 ? 0 : hundreds + 1;
                if(hundreds == 9) begin
                     thousands <= thousands + 1; 
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: counting up is a good idea but my concern is that i am trying to run a vga monitor and im not sure it could keep up.

Comment: I used your method but it did not work, just produced a haze accross my screen